# Charging all night and its effect on the charger

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-consumption

I googled about this topic and I found that keeping the charger plugged in the wall for days will consume a very small amount of energy and will not cost too much. And most of smart phones disconnect the battery from the charger automatically when the battery is fully charged. So The battery, The phone, and The money are in safe.

What about the charger itself? If I keep it plugged in the wall mains for all night or for many days, Does that affect the life time? I would NOT like to buy a new charger every month :)

Comment: /me looks over at the dozens of adapters he has plugged in to the mains...

Comment: Shouldn't really harm it. It does increase exposure to transients, surges etc, and if the charger is cheaply designed it may be more susceptible to such accidents. As wall outlets here are switched I just switch them off at the socket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failure of electronic components can be caused by a range of different mechanisms, but the common factors that accelerate failure are heat, applied voltage and applied current.

If your charger is well designed, and stays cool, and your mains doesn't suffer from large voltage spikes, then I wouldn't expect it to fail from staying plugged in - at least not within the expected lifetime of the device it was intended to charge. If the charger is allowed to continually get hot because of poor ventilation, or if it's badly designed or cheaply made such that one or more components are operated close to or outside their voltage, current or power handling capabilities, then I guess unplugging it when not in use might extend its lifespan.

There are some failure mechanisms that arise from thermal cycling, i.e. alternate heating up and cooling down, which might argue for leaving the charger powered, but it'll probably undergo thermal cycling anyway because it will heat up when charging a device and cool down again when idle.

(Some background information on failure mechanisms of [electrolytic capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor#Lifetime) and [semiconductors](http://rel.intersil.com/docs/rel/calculation_of_semiconductor_failure_rates.pdf), which I would guess are the most failure-prone non-mechanical parts of a switch-mode charger circuit.)